# How to work with the "type"/"method" set in the AJAX request in the PHP API

Tags: php, ajax, api

I created a PHP API to work with userdata saved in a database. I access it via AJAX requests.

When I start an AJAX request, it looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  ...
});
```

My question is: how does the receiving *.php-file know what it is supposed to do? AJAX determines, that it is supposed to be a GET-request but in the *.php-file there is code to get users, save users (POST), update users (PUT) and so on. Do I have to build a `switch-case-statement` in the *.php-file?

Or am I missunderstanding a concept here?

Comment: This is the type of HTTP request. It does not necessarily determine your business logic.

Comment: You can have different files for different actions? Or better yet, use a router. As far as PHP is concerned, it doesn't care if the request is an Ajax request or an "ordinary" request (browser, form submission etc).

Comment: but can I grab the "type"/"method" in the *.php-file and work with it? What if I have program code to do serveral user-related things in one file but I only want to execute a piece depending on the request method (e.g. when it is a GET-request, it makes no sense to execute code to create a user, in fact it may produce an error due to the missing data)

Comment: anymore ideas or help? :/